# Elementary OS Wifi not available

Tags: settings, boot, wifi, networking, error

I often incur the issue that the Wifi connections are not shown. Neither is the WIfi functionality displayed in settings (see photos attached to this post).

This occurs every 3-5 boots, and rebooting always fixes the problem. However, how can I avoid this problem in the first place?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can not offer a solution, but this affects me as well. This happens often after my notebook wakes up from suspend. With USB WiFi card I need to re-plug it, so the WiFi is availible again. No luck so fat solving this issue. Could you try to take a look at the otput of dmesg after it happens again?

Comment: Your question was also placed https://github.com/elementary/triage/discussions/51 due to the request to start copying questions to that site.